# Site’s first loading on a new browser with no cache is messed up

Tags: cache

When I start my website on a new browser everything is messed up, and looking like it is missing the CSS ( doesn't look like it misses HTML tho). The problem can be minimized by surfing threw the site and gaining some cache ( i guess? ) but this is just a temporary solution which might not work for some new site's visitors.

The theme used is Hello Elementor and below there is a picture of how it looks when you first open the site on a new browser as well as the picture of how on the browser it has been developed on ( logged in elementor). Last picture is the picture of plugins i use.

[image: New Browser]

[image]

Comment: I've fixed some of the formatting in your question, but the images are hosted offsite. Use the edit link underneath the tag lsit to update your question to include the images directly, questions must be self contained, you can't use a 3rd party host.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know i will fix this

Comment: If it is the gaining-cache issue you suggested then I'd try browsing your site with the browser debug tools open so you can see which files are slow or failing to load. You'll then have to track down how they are hosted and why they're being served slowly. Do you have any plugins that would e.g. minify CSS or JS on the fly?